# Selecting 1st letter and comparing

Tags: r, frameworks

I need to compare 1st letter from column 1 to 1st letter in 3 and last letter from column 1 to first letter in column 4 and show results when both are true. Example data:

```
column1 <- c("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor")
column2 <- c("one","two","three")
column3 <- c("lello", "world","hello")
column4 <- c("mo","me","ri")
data.frame(column1, column2, column4)
```

Since the first observation meets both criteria, the resulting dataframe should include only row 1.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Generally you should provide a simple reproducible example with your question. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substring` or `substr` to extract a string at a particular position.

```
df$match <- with(df, substring(A, 1, 1) == substring(C, 1, 1) & 
                     substring(A, nchar(A)) == substring(D, 1, 1))

df
#      A      B        C     D match
#1  NINE ABCDEF NEW YORK EAGLE  TRUE
#2   TWO  ADSDD   LONDON   DOG FALSE
#3 THREE ASWERR    TOKYO   CAT FALSE
```

If we want to subset those observations instead of adding a new column, we can use `subset`

```
subset(df, substring(A, 1, 1) == substring(C, 1, 1) & 
           substring(A, nchar(A)) == substring(D, 1, 1))

#     A      B        C     D
#1 NINE ABCDEF NEW YORK EAGLE
```

**data**

Consider a sample data

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("NINE", "TWO", "THREE"), B = c("ABCDEF", "ADSDD", "ASWERR"), 
                 C = c("NEW YORK", "LONDON", "TOKYO"), D = c("EAGLE", "DOG", "CAT"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```